# Simple Dynamically adding and using objects

Tags: c++, vector

I am not sure how to properly do this, first i created a vector to store objects, for example

```
vector<dog> mydogs;
```

After that i have a function that add dogs to my vector every time i press space bar, so now i tried to do this,

```
mydogs.pushback(new dog());
```

It was complaining that the argument type did not match, so i change the vector to the code bellow because i want to store pointers on my vector.

```
vector<&dog> mydogs;
```

I have this simple iterator that i want to check the state of dogs and do something with them.

```
for(auto x = mydogs.begin(); x != mydogs.end();x++){...}
```

But i can't access the iterator now, i am kind of lost even think of this.

Comment: [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector of pointers to dogs:

```
std::vector<dog *>
```

When you use the `new` operator, it returns a pointer.  So if you want dynamically allocated doggies try this:

```
  std::vector<dog *> animals;
  //...
  animals.push_back(new dog);
```

I suggest you look at smart pointers because the `vector` will not deallocate memory that a `dog` occupies; it just destroys the leash.

Comment: i get that part, the problems that i have is access it with the iterator that I've showed above.

Comment: To access a dog:  `animals[4]->bark();`  To access using an iterator:  `(*iterator)->bark();`

Comment: Thanks, that's was what i wanted. But why do i have to use parentheses + star and why doesn't the deference operator work on that?

Comment: The iterator is a pointer.  Dereferencing the iterator refers to an item in the vector, which is a pointer to a dog.  So dereferencing the iterator yields a pointer.  The parenthesis is for readability and to control the precedence.  The parenthesis shows that the contents inside are a pointer and that the `bark` method is associated with that item.  Otherwise, you have to double derefence then access the member, something like `**iter.bark()`.  This raises the question of what the '.' belongs to.  The other choice is `*iter->bark()`, which asks "what is the -> applied to?"

Answer (score 2):

*Whelp.* Your first attempt was pretty fine. You want to store a collection of dogs, neither references nor pointers.

```
vector<dog> mydogs;
```

If you want to add a puppy, you can simply resize your container:

```
mydogs.resize(mydogs.size() + 1);
```

Or if you have a *specific* dog, you can add it too:

```
dog LordFleuroVanHautendeck;
mydogs.push_back(LordFleuroVanHautendeck);
```

Or even in one line:

```
mydogs.push_back(dog()); // poor dog has no name
```

The last line might look similar to your original line, but the missing `new` is quite important. `dog()` will be a `dog`, which can be used on `vector<dog>::push_back()`, while `new dog` (which is `dog*`) can't.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
new dog()
```

returns a **pointer** (`dog*`) to a newly allocated object. Just use

```
vector<dog> mydogs;
```

and create new elements with

```
mydogs.push_back(dog());
```

If you really want to create dynamically an instance of dog by the `new` keyword, you may want to use

```
vector<dog*> mydogs;
mydogs.push_back(new dog());
```

but remember, you've created an object dynamically, so eventually you have to use `delete` keyword to avoid a memory leak:

```
while(mydogs.size() > 0){
    delete mydogs.back(); // delete the dog
    mydogs.pop_back();    // get rid of the pointer
}
```